# Change style.css by changing language in php

Tags: php, css, right-to-left, multilingual

Does anyone know how to use condition in CSS?

I'm using PHP Script The thing is that I have 4 files with these names **"style.css","style-rtl.css","bootstrap.min.css","bootstrap-rtl.min.css"** that sometimes may be in **RTL** language.

So I want some sort of PHP code or any other solution that can detect if the language is Ar and set the direction to **RTL** with **style-rtl.css & bootstrap-rtl.min.css** , else language is En set direction to **LTR** and use **style.css & bootstrap.min.css** .

Here is some `header.php` code:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Component CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/themes/<?php echo $this->config["theme"] ?>/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/themes/<?php echo $this->config["theme"] ?>/style-rtl.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/components.min.css">
```

Comment: Detect the language from where? Do you not save the language with the content in your database?

Comment: So, You want to manipulate css and bootstrap according to user's language...

Comment: this script is multilanguage but not multi style and language does change with this tag  at the end of domain "/?lang=en" and "/?lang=ar"

Comment: `<link href="bootstrap<?php echo ($_GET['lang'] == 'ar') ? '-rtl' : '' ?>.min.css">`

Comment: @azeós not work :(

Comment: @ShivamArora yes

Comment: Did you add `?lang=ar` to de URL? What `href` did you get?

Comment: @azeós yes add your code in header buttom of my codes , and loading url with ?lang=ar but rtl style not load

Comment: Just to be clear, this is the complete code: `<link href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/bootstrap<?php echo ($_GET['lang'] == 'ar') ? '-rtl' : '' ?>.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Use that instead of the two Bootstrap links you have and do the same with the `style.css`. Or you need to include the LTR and RTL at the same time?

Comment: @azeós thaks man , your code is greate,

Comment: @azeós I think the problem was replacing the codes by me

Comment: Test what happens if there is no `?lang`, maybe you need to check if `isset($_GET['lang'])`.

Comment: in homepage is correct but when goes to another page without `?lang` ltr.css is loading

Comment: do you now how can i adding `isset($_GET['lang'])` with `if` & `else` for correct css loading in another page without  `?lang` ??

Comment: _“in homepage is correct but when goes to another page without ?lang ltr.css is loading”_ - yeah well obviously this won’t work, if that parameter is not present in the URL. If your system manages to still show the content in the correct language on those other pages, then it must have stored the information somewhere after the first page was called with this parameter - in a cookie, the session, … It’s your site, so you should know.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with :

```
    <?PHP
if(isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    switch($_SESSION['lang']):
    case 'eng':
        // LTR Style
        ?>
        <link href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/themes/<?php echo $this->config["theme"] ?>/style.css">
        <?PHP
    break;
    case 'ar':
        // RTL Style
        ?>
        <link href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/bootstrap-rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/themes/<?php echo $this->config["theme"] ?>/style-rtl.css">    
        <?PHP

    break;
    default:
        ?>
        <link href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->config["url"] ?>/themes/<?php echo $this->config["theme"] ?>/style.css">
        <?PHP
    endswitch;
}
?>
```